# how to auto refresh div tag to retrieve data from database with online member?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to find some source code which can auto refresh every 30 second on my div tag. I think there is only javascript can be done. I am confusing how to do it. Can anyone tell me what can I do?

this is my php code :

```
<?php $sql = $getUser->getuser(); 
      if ($rs = $db->Execute($stmt)) { 
          $arrResult = array(); 
          while($rsa = $rs->FetchRow()) { 
              array_push($arrResult, array("username" => $rsa['username'] )); 
          } 
      } 
?>
```

and this is my div tag in my html which will display online user

```
     <body onload="timer = setTimeout('auto_reload()',10000);">
<{section name=thisrsa loop=$rsa max=$max}>
    <div>
    <td><{$rsa[thisrsa].username}></td>
    </div>
    <{/section}>
```

and it will display like this at one of the site in html page:

```
-----------
|jimmy    |
|Anderson |
|simon    |
|vincent  |
-----------
```

this is what i use to control my div

```
<script>
var timer = null;
function auto_reload()
{
    window.location = 'http://domain.com/page.php';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try using ajax?

Comment: why dont you use ajax ?

Comment: There is no content when the page loading - Right ?

Comment: how to do so? can you provide me a sample code to integrate to my code?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a portal where people should pass you the code on request. Please do an attempt by yourself, show us what you've tried so far and provide a code example, you mention javascript but have not tried to write one line.

Comment: because my javascript is not function perfect. therefore, i don't want to confuse you all who try to help me. i appreciate that you correct me. thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there any source code for show member online?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604875/is-there-any-source-code-for-show-member-online)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "give me code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do not know this sample code will run properly inside your project or not. but if you do not feel trouble. if you have free time you can try this code.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Ajax(){
var xmlHttp;
    try{    
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    }catch (e){
        try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
        }catch (e){
            try{
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e){
                alert("No AJAX!?");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('Ajax()',2000);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET","text.txt",true);
    xmlHttp.send(null); 
}
window.onload=function(){
    setTimeout('Ajax()',2000);
}
</script>
<div id="ReloadThis">Default text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend Ajax call instead of xmlHttp for crossbrowser support

Answer (score 0):

since your php code to get data is on the same page you got to refresh the page in every 30 seconds to get the latest data which can be done this way:

```
window.setInterval(function(){window.location = window.location.href},30000);
```

if your php code to retrieve data was in next page you could simply make ajax request to that page to fetch the updated data  and update the div with the new data

```
 window.setInterval(function(){//ajax request //},30000);
```

Comment: is this code will refresh window?

Comment: yeah it will..You can check it...

Comment: window.location.reload(); also does the same job

Comment: due to this code will be one pf the part inside my home page. therefore, if there will keep refresh window it will make the page become inconvenience to my user. any alternative way to do it?

Comment: the next way is write the php code to get the latest data  in next page that will return data on request. and you got to use ajax  to make request to the next page every 30 seconds and it will return the updated data in response .you can use that response to update the div

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax  you can learn more about ajax here

Comment: And here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that implements JQuery/Javascript:

First, create a separate PHP page that will echo/contain ONLY the data you wish to populate the div with.

From your main page you can then use JQuery/Javascript to create a function that will both set the innerhtml of the div as the content of this separate page and refresh the div every 30 seconds by recursively calling itself using `setTimeout`.

```
<script>
    function reloadData() {

        $('#divIDHere').load("separatePage.php");
        setTimeout(function() {reloadData(); }, 30000);
    }
</script>
```

To do this you will need to import the JQuery min file into your page. You can download this at 'http://jquery.com/download/'.
You can then import this into your page by including the following HTML:

`<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

Now you have a separate page that echos the data you want into your div and a JQuery/Javascript function that will both set the content of the div to equal the separate page and refresh the div every 30 seconds.

All that is left to do is make the page call the function you have created. This can be done by including the following HTML:

`<script>reloadData();</script>`

Answer (score 0):

To use this code your php file must echo

```
<?php $sql = $getUser->getuser(); 
      if ($rs = $db->Execute($stmt)) { 
          $arrResult = array(); 
          while($rsa = $rs->FetchRow()) { 
              $output.=$rsa['username']."<br>"; 
          } 

          echo $output;
      } 
?>
```

HTML - Response will be shown in the #logins

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
Ajax();
setTimeout('Ajax()',30000);

function Ajax(){
    $.post("ligin_check.php", { //This whoulb be youe php file

    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $("#logins").html(data);

    }).fail(function() {
        ("#logins").html( "error" );
    });

}

});



</script>
<div id="logins">Waiting...</div>
</body>
</html>
```